# Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found error when Client is instantiated

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to integrate Twilio into my application. When I run their sample code, it runs perfectly fine:

```
require_once "twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$AccountSid = "XXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "XXXXXX";

$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$sms = $client->account->messages->create(
    "+15555555555",
    array(
        'from' => "+15556665566",
        'body' => "Hey, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
    )
);
```

However, when I try to integrate it into a class, I keep getting a PHP Fatal Error Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found every time it executes. This is the code in my class:

```
require_once "twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class Customer{
    //constructors etc

    public function sendText(){
        $AccountSid = "XXXXXX";
        $AuthToken = "XXXXXX";

        $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
        $sms = $client->account->messages->create(
            '+15555555555',
            array(
                'from' => "+15556665566",
                'body' => "Hey, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I've checked the opening tags in the Twilio Library, I've ensured that the file location is correct (it throws the error when the

```
$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

line is executed, not at the require_once) but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Where is this class located in your project directory and where is the Twilio library located?

Comment: The class is located in a directory named 'module' and the Twilio library is in the same.
Class file: <root>/module/Customer.class.php
Library:    <root>/module/twilio-php-master/Twilio

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what's happening here. I have tried to reproduce this myself and I can't. Do you have another class named `Client` somewhere? Is the `use` statement definitely at the top of the file and not nested inside a class or function?

Comment: What happens if you fully specify the path to Client? eg. `$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);`

Comment: @Andy I have two scripts where I send SMS via Twilio API. On one script, it works the way OP has it. After spending hours trying to make the second script work with the same code, only your solution in your comment made it work. I have no idea why the first code works in first script and not in second script, but thank you for the comment!